# how to place global variables placed adjacent? (without setting it at linker script)

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, volatile

I want to place 3 variables 32 bytes apart adjacent with each other. This is for debugging, a suspicious behavior.
For this line of C code (sparc, bare-metal, defining a global variable outside a function.)

```
int __attribute__ ((aligned (32))) xx0, layer_complete, xx1;
```

With just this code, the variables xx0, xx1, layer_complete are aligned to 32 byte but just after layer_complete, there are some variables placed. I want only one variable to be placed in a 32 bit range. (having said that, I have an idea of using union. but I'm curious if I can do it without union).

ADD : I tried this with union (to make some space after layer_complete)

```
union ttt {
    int layer_complete;
    int a[8]; // to make it 32 bytes
} __attribute__((aligned(32))) lc_union;
#define layer_complete lc_union.layer_complete
```

inspecting program.map I can see layer_complete is 32 byte aligned and the following 28 bytes are not used (of course).

Comment: What is your platform/compiler/target? What happens if you remove `__attribute__ ((aligned (32)))`?

Comment: BTW: 1: `volatile` has nothing to do with variables being optimized away or not. 2: non static global variables won't be optimized away anyway.

Comment: this is sparc/gcc/baremetal. if I remove aligned, it will not be aligned. I wanted it to be separate from other variables (to be assigned in different cache line). It was there historically. yes, now I'm using io access (bypassing cache) for layer_complete, so aligned may not be necessary.

Comment: I saw the variable optimized away when volatile is not there. the variable is written by interrupt routine and read by main thread. and the compiler thinks it is not used. (I thought it weird but it happened in the past)

Comment: OK, I misunderstood, "Variable access optimized away" is not the same thing as "variable optimized away".

Comment: Does it _compile_ if you remove `__attribute__ ((aligned (32)))`?

Comment: I changed question. without aligned attribute they are not aligned. (some aligned, some not).

Comment: Now you completely changed the question... No more _error: conflicting type qualifiers for 'layer_complete'_ problems now??

Comment: Do you have an option of simply putting these vars into a struct? If the struct instance has the same scope, emitted assembly would likely be the same. i.e. `struct Vars { uint32_t a; uint32_t b; uint32_t c; uint32_t d; }` and then `struct Vars __attribute__ ((aligned (32))) vars;`.

Comment: What's the reasoning behing `int a[7]; // to make it 32 bytes`? Why not `char a[32];`?

Comment: ah, my mistake. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
typedef struct
{
   int _Alignas(32) xx0;
   int _Alignas(32) layer_complete;
   int _Alignas(32) xx1;
} thing;
...
thing t;
```

If you for some reason is using a very old version of gcc (pre-C11, 4.x something or older), then you can also use non-standard `__attribute__ ((aligned (32)))`.

Since this is just for debugging purposes, you could make macros such as `#define xx0 t.xx0` to make the struct compatible with what you already got.

Answer (score 0):

With something like that :

```
char memVar96[96];

void *ptr1 = memVar96;
void *ptr2 = &memVar96[32];
void *ptr3 = &memVar96[64];

#define var1  (*(MyVarType1*)ptr1)
#define var2  (*(MyVarType2*)ptr2)
#define var3  (*(MyVarType3*)ptr3)
```

Comment: This won't work reliably, because every `*(MyVarType1*)` is a strict aliasing violation UB. To use this method, you'd have to place `memVar96` in a union with the actual types to be stored at that location. And from there, it quickly gets complex and unreadable. You'd have to do something like `typedef union
{
  char dummy [96];
  struct
  {
    MyVarType1 var1;
    MyVarType2 var1;
    MyVarType3 var1;
  };
} foo;`